# Use Range.subTotal without listing all indexes of an Array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to avoid listing all the indexes of array colNums(8,9,10,.....,60) in order to use the subTotal function. When I just use colNums() as an argument for totallist Excel does not provide subtotals, however, when I list all the indexes of the array as in ColNums(8,9,10....,60) the subTotal works. How can I achieve the same with just colNums() ?. Thanks.

```
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim colNums() as Integer
    ReDim colNums(rs.Fields.Count)
    n = 0

    For m = 8 To rs.Fields.Count

      colNums(n) = m

      n = n + 1

    Next m   

      Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, totallist:=colNums(), Replace:=True, _

     pagebreaks:=False, summarybelowdata:=False
```

Comment: `ReDim colNums(rs.Fields.Count - 7)` you are providing 7 `0` items and there is no column `0`.

Comment: And `colNums` MAY need to be a variant array.